# Why is my heat pump blowing cold air?

Tags: heat

Two days ago our heat pump start putting out cold air and it's 30 degrees outside. We changed to emergency heat, but we don't know what is wrong. On regular heat it blows cold air.

On emergency heat it keeps the house warm, but it has the aux heat on also, which I think is more expensive.

Comment: You should include the make and model of all the equipment involved. Including the local weather condition when the problem was occurring, would also be helpful.

Comment: heil heat pump, temp at the time of malfunction was somewhere around 30+ degrees. I have since learned that the unit maybe defrosting and this is normal. Will the emergency heat affect the defrosting stage?

Comment: If it is 30 degrees outside, and your heat pump is putting out cold air, I would assume that your AC is working and it is doing its job. Please correct your question and specify 30°F if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's easiest to say that you need to get an HVAC maintenance company to come check on it. The auxiliary heat is entirely separate from the heat pump, that is why it's also used as an emergency system.

However, how cold has it been recently? A heat pump will only work to around 34 degrees or so outside and then it should switch off and allow the auxiliary to heat the home alone. Without going into too many details about the various possibilities, it could be that it's too cold outside for the heat pump, but the auxiliary isn't taking over (an issue with the thermostat and it's wiring to the system.) In regular heating mode, your heat pumps runs until it's too cold outside, and then the auxiliary takes over. In emergency heating, the auxiliary runs only. However, if it's been below say 34 degrees for those last two days, then your auxiliary would have been running entirely anyway and you wouldn't be saving any.

Again though, it's an advanced system and this could be caused by multiple issues - have someone come look at it.

[image: Heat pumping system for heat]